# Algebraic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am wondering, if you consider a polynomial in two variables like

$$P(x,y)=0,$$

and a zero $P(a,b)=0$ exists fulfilling $P_y(a,b)=0$ and $P_x(a,b)=0$, is there continuity in the sense of

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0: \ |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow \exists y: |y-b|<\epsilon \quad \mbox{and} \ P(x,y)=0.$$

If at least one partial derivative exists it is clear by implicit function theorem, but in this case I am not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer, I misunderstood your question.  I still find the exposition a bit confusing so you may want to see if there is a nicer way of wording it.

Comment: My guess is you mean $|y-b|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Of course i edited it.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least over the real numbers.

Consider $P(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $a=b=0$.
Then $P_x(a,b)=P_y(a,b)=0$, but $P$ has only one zero. In particular every neighbourhood of $a$ has values for $x$ such that no zero exists with this value as first coordinate.

In the complex case, I believe the answer is *yes*. The roots of a polynomial depend continuously on its coefficients ([wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Continuous_dependence_of_coefficients)), and we can consider $P(x,y)$ as a polynomial in $y$ whose coefficients depend (continuously) on $x$.

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that it has *complex* zeroes arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Of course i am considering the complex case. so set $y(x)=ix$ and its true.

Comment: @Analyst77 - Aha. This was not clear to me.

Comment: @Analyst77 - Added complex case to my answer.